# Iterators, value of result of call to end() changes as data is added to circular_buffer

Tags: c++, boost, iterator, std, circular-buffer

I discovered earlier today that the iterators of a `boost::circular` buffer were not behaving quite as I expected them to in a multi-threaded environment. (although to be fair they behave differently than I would think in a single threaded program too).

if you make calls to `buffer.begin()` and `buffer.end()` to represent iterators to use to loop over a specific seqment of data. The value of the end iterator changes if more data is added to the `circular_buffer`. Obviously you would expect to get a different result if you made another call to `end()` after the data was changed. But what is confusing is the value of the iterator object you already made changing.

Is there a way to create iterators that allow you to work on a set range of data in a circular_buffer and do not have their values changed even if additional data is added to the buffer while working on a range?

If not, is there a preferred 'non-iterator' pattern that might apply, or a different container class that might allow this?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <boost\thread.hpp>
#include <boost\thread\thread_time.hpp>
#include <boost\circular_buffer.hpp>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    boost::circular_buffer<int> buffer(20);

    buffer.push_back(99);
    buffer.push_back(99);
    buffer.push_back(99);

    boost::circular_buffer<int>::const_iterator itBegin = buffer.begin();
    boost::circular_buffer<int>::const_iterator itEnd = buffer.end();

    int count = itEnd - itBegin;
    printf("itEnd - itBegin == %i\n", count); //prints 3

    /* another thread (or this one) pushes an item*/
    buffer.push_back(99);

    /*we check values of begin and end again, they've changed, even though we have not done anything in this thread*/
    count = itEnd - itBegin;
    printf("itEnd - itBegin == %i\n", count); //prints 4 
}
```

---

Update for more detailed response to ronag
I am looking for a producer consumer type model, and the bounded buffer example shown in the boost documentation is CLOSE to what I need. with the following two exceptions.

1. I need to be able to read more than one element of data off the buffer at a time, inspect them, which may not be trivial, and then choose how many items to to remove from the buffer.

   fake example: trying to process the two words hello & world from a string of characters.

   read 1, buffer contains h-e-l, do not remove chars from the buffer.
   -more producing
   read 2, buffer contains h-e-l-l-o-w-o, I found 'hello' remove 5 chars, buffer now has w-o
   -more producing
   read 3, buffer contains w-o-r-l-d, process 'world', remove another 5 characters.
2. I need to not block the producer thread when reading, unless the buffer is full.

Comment: It's possible that `push_back` invalidates iterators so that you end up with UB.

Comment: In this sample code given, `push_back` will not invalidate any iterators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [boost::circular_buffer::iterator docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/circular_buffer/index.html#iteratorinvalidation), your iterators should remain valid.  (Always the first thing I check when mutating and iterating a container at the same time.)  So your example code is legal.

What is happening is due to STL iterator convention: `end()` doesn't point at an element, but rather to the imaginary one-past-the-last element.  After the fourth `push_back`, the distance from `itBegin` (the first element) to `itEnd` (one-past-the-last element) has increased.

One solution may be to hold an iterator pointing to a concrete element, e.g.

```
itPenultimate = itEnd - 1;
```

Now the distance from `itBegin` to `itPenultimate` will remain the same even when the circular buffer is extended, as long as it's not in the range.

Comment: I (and the OP) do not see why calling `push_back` on the container causes the local variable `itEnd` to change.

Comment: @MooingDuck The `push_back` inserted an element *before* `itEnd`, thus causing the distance from `itBegin` to `itEnd` to increase.  The same would happen if you inserted into the buffer between any two iterators.

Comment: @MooingDuck `count` doesn't change, and neither does `itEnd`.  What does change is `itEnd - itBegin`.  It's like holding both ends of a chain and somebody inserting a link in the middle.

Comment: You're right, bad example.  A better clarifier is: why doesn't it act like `vector`/`deque`/`array`?  Instead, it's acting like the node-based containers.  `boost::circular_buffer` seems like it should act like a `vector`/`deque`/`array`.

Comment: Good explanation, I ended up implementing a custom iterator using boost::iterator_facade which gave me the behavior that I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

The doc explicitly states that circular buffer [is not thread-safe](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/circular_buffer/doc/circular_buffer.html#threadsafety) and that the user is responsible for locking the data structure. That would remedy your problem.

But maybe a producer-consumer style queue is better suited for your problem.